# Adding a boarder to the bottom of a ListView.Header

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Here's what I tried so far:

```
<ListView RowHeight="50">
   <ListView.Header>
      <Grid>
         <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="49" />
            <RowDefinition Height="1" />
         </Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <Label Grid.Row="0" BackgroundColor="#EEEEEE" Text="ABC" />
         <BoxView Grid.Row="1" BackgroundColor="#999" HeightRequest="1" />
      </Grid>
   </ListView.Header>
   <ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

I had expected to see a top area color EEE and below that a line of height 1 and color 999

However between the EEE color and the 999 line there is a white area that's about 3-4 px high.

Does anyone know why it is that there is this and how I can change it so that the 999 line appears directly below the EEE color area?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's because of the default `RowSpacing` value* of the grid (6). Set `<Grid RowSpacing="0">` to get rid of it.

**See more [at the source code of Grid class](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Core/Grid.cs).*

Despite this, I suggest you use the StackLayout (with `Spacing="0"`) instead of Grid if your layout is exactly as you show. Like this:

```
<StackLayout Spacing="0">
    <Label BackgroundColor="#EEEEEE" 
           Text="ABC"
           HeightRequest="49"/>
    <BoxView BackgroundColor="#999" 
             HeightRequest="1" />
</StackLayout>
```

Results (First with Grid, second with StackLayout):

[image: Sample]

Comment: With a StackLayout, can I still specify the heights ?

Comment: Of course . But in this case it would be specified at the elements, like `Label HeightRequest="49"` and adjust the vertical text alignment may be needed.

Comment: can u give an example of what the XAML would look like.  I will accept ur answer

Answer (score 2):

Use a negative margin on the row above, thus your "ABC" row use a bottom margin of `-6`.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="49" />
        <RowDefinition Height="1" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Label Grid.Row="0" BackgroundColor="#EEEEEE" Text="ABC" Margin="0,0,0,-6" />
    <BoxView Grid.Row="1" BackgroundColor="#999" HeightRequest="1" />
</Grid>
```